# Bifurcation Near Origin of one parameter families of maps

Tags: dynamical-systems, stability-in-odes, stability-theory, bifurcation

I am working on a problem out of "An Introduction to Applied Nonlinear Dynamical Systems and Chaos" by S. Wiggins. Section 3 is all about local bifurcations and I am asked to describe the bifurcation of the origin of the following systems, and to compare them.

$$\dot{x}=x-2y+\epsilon x$$
$$\dot{y}=3x-y-x^2$$

I put them in normal form, 
$$\begin{bmatrix}\dot{x}\\ \dot{y}\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}
1 & -2 \\
3 & -1 
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}x\\
y\end{bmatrix}+\begin{bmatrix}\epsilon x\\-x^2\end{bmatrix}.$$

I think this is the case because the linear part has eigen values with zero real parts. I'm supposed to introduce a parameter $\dot{\epsilon}=0$ to find the equation of the stable manifold using the standard partial differential equation $$\mathcal{N}(h(x,\epsilon))=0=D_xh(x,\epsilon)\left[Ax+f(x,h(x,\epsilon),\epsilon)\right]-Bh(x,\epsilon)-g(x,h(x,\epsilon),\epsilon)$$.

I think $A$ is the linear part of the above equation, $B$ is zero, $g$ is zero and $f$ is the nonlinear part. I am unsure of how to fully use this equation. My professors lecture is incomplete and I cannot find anything online.

The system that I am comparing it with is $$\dot{x}=x-2y+\epsilon x^2$$
$$\dot{y}=3x-y-x^2$$

Comment: @JohnB well I found the Jordan normal form of the linear part and then transformed the non linear part. I assumed the center manifold is approximated by a quadratic in two variables, $u$ and $\epsilon$, but when I write out the components for $mathcal{N}$ I keep getting only terms that are higher than order two.

Answer (score 0):

In this case all turns out to be simpler. Note first that the equation can be written in the form
$$
\begin{bmatrix}\dot{x}\\ \dot{y}\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}
1+\epsilon & -2 \\
3 & -1 
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}x\\
y\end{bmatrix}+\begin{bmatrix}0\\-x^2\end{bmatrix}.
$$
The eigenvalues of the matrix $$\begin{bmatrix}
1+\epsilon & -2 \\
3 & -1 
\end{bmatrix}$$ are
$$
\frac{1}{2} \left(\epsilon\pm\sqrt{\epsilon^2+4 \epsilon-20}\right)\approx \frac{\epsilon}{2} \pm i\sqrt{5}
$$
for $\epsilon$ very close to zero.

> So there are two eigenvalues with **negative** real part for $\epsilon<0$ very close to zero and here are two eigenvalues with **positive** real part for $\epsilon>0$ very close to zero.

This implies that you pass from a stable focus to an unstable focus as $\epsilon$ travels from some negative value close to zero to some positive value close to zero (since the eigenvalues have nonzero real part the term $-x^2$ does not change the topological behavior of the linear part in a small neighborhood of the origin).

These are roughly the phase portraits in a neighborhood of the origin:

$\hskip2in$ [image]

for small $\epsilon<0$ and

$\hskip2in$ [image]

for small $\epsilon>0$.

Comment: This is the way i first approached the problem, but I am being required to use the center manifold theorem and $\mathcal{N}(h(x,\epsilon))$ to approximate the center manifold. Every time i do the calculation for $h$ i get higher order terms and an overdetermined system for the coefficients. Thank you for the in depth answer though

Comment: The center manifold is $3$-dimensional on a $3$-dimensional space when you add $\dot \epsilon=0$ so nobody will do it as you say.

Comment: It seems odd to me as well, considering I did it the way you did the first time, but she said I need to redo it by finding the center manifold and using the parameter $\epsilon$. But now from you I see that the center manifold is 3D since there are 3 eigen values with zero real part. I was using an $h$ with two components. Do I need to adjust that $h$ to three components. If so how would I go  about that? Would all my terms be cubic for the components of $h$?

Comment: I have already replied to what you asked, so please ask a different question if you think that it is appropriate. As I said: nobody will do it as you say, so I really can't help more here. Sorry.